# How to get multiple result using Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5

I can get first result using this code

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $record = St::where('pn', $request->input)->first();
    $param = ['input' => $request->input, 'record' =>$record];
    return view('contacts.find', $param);

}
```

but, I changed like this

$record = St::where('pn', $request->input)->get();

error show up

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getData does not exist

Could someone tell me why?

my version is 5.6

```
store {#717 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:20 [▶]
  #original: array:20 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

blade file

```
 @if (isset($record))
    <table>
    <tr><th>result</th></tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{{$record->getResult()}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    @endif
```

and this is Class

```
class st extends Model
{

    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->pn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the error really coming from that line? Not from your view?

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir Hi. Yeah. this error pops up.  I red manual of laravel  it say. change -> first  to ->get . if you want many result.  I've stock this  6 hours...

Comment: Put `dd($record);` before `return`. What's the result?

Comment: Mr. @Jonas Staudenmeir I add some info. thank you.

Comment: I meant when you use `get()` instead of `first()` to get `$record`.

Comment: Mr. @ Jonas Staudenmeir Sorry! its a Collection {#763 ▼
  #items: array:23 [▶]
}

Comment: This means that `get()` isn't causing the error. How do you use `$record` in your view?

Comment: Mr. @Jonas Staudenmeir I update my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$record` is a collection when you use `get()`. So you have to use a loop to access individual instances. You should also rename it to `$records`:

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $records = St::where('pn', $request->input)->get();
    $param = ['input' => $request->input, 'records' => $records];
    return view('contacts.find', $param);
}


@foreach($records as $record)
   {{ $record->getResult() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I appreciate your help . I got this error  Undefined variable: records

Comment: Do you still use `@if (isset($record))`?

Comment: Hi. @Jonas Staudenmeir .Thank you. foreach goes well.  Sorry for late reply. I delete getResult() and isset($record). Thanks again.